# Can't call setState in componentWillMount() multiple times, what is workaround React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, state

So I have fetch() which gets me an array. So I store that array in state, and after that I do some function and when it's done I want to set state again so I stop loading. Here is code that will explain it better(all this code is in componentWillMount() btw):

```js
// before this is just simple unimportant get request
.then(responseJson => {
            // loading here is 1
            this.setState(function (prevState, props) {
                return {questions: responseJson}
            })

            this.makeAnswers(responseJson)

            // loading needs to be 0 here

        })
```

If you need more info please comment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you put the `this.setState({loading: 0})` inside your `makeAnswers()` function?

Just check if you need to do that:

```
makeAnswers = (response) => {
  ...
  if (this.state.loading !== 0) this.setState({loading: 0})
}
```

Comment: that is good logic but it does not work... again says I can't call setState bcz it creates some infinite loop.

Comment: Do you need to set `questions` in the state before running `makeAnswers()` ?
Because if not, you could run the `makeAnswers()` function and then `this.setState()` with both `questions` and `loading` (all inside `componentWillMount()`)

Comment: Dude, you are smart

Comment: What if you put `makeAnswers()` inside the `setState` function? (Just trying to help, I don't really know why it does't work)

Comment: Doesn't work... i hate this moments in react native where you just don't know what to do.

Comment: @crodev Can you move to the componentDidMount() method?

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to await the promise of the first setState before calling your makeAnswers function.

```
.then(async response => {
        // This will ensure questions is set in the state before calling makeAnswers
        await this.setState({questions: response.questions})

        this.makeAnswers(response.questions)

        this.setState({ loading: false })

    })
```

If you set the state inside makeAnswers also, you can just set the loading state there. Like

```
    componentDidMount = () => {
        fetch()
        .then(async response => {
            // This will ensure questions is set in the state before calling makeAnswers
            await this.setState({questions: response.questions})
            this.makeAnswers(response.questions)

        })
    }


    makeAnswers = questions => {
        //...do something 
        this.setState({ answers: something, loading: false })
    }
```